# How to change my code

Tags: python, function, optimization

If I give negative numbers this code does not function any more and I don't know how to stop it if I put for example a string or something that doesn't have sense. Help me please!!

```
def computeHCF(x,y):

        if x>y:
            smaller = y
        else:
            smaller = x
        for i in range(1, smaller+1):
            if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
                hcf = i
        return hcf

    while True:
        num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
        print("The H.C.F. of", num1,"and", num2,"is", computeHCF(num1, num2))
        continue;
    else:
        print("You write something that doesn't have any sense!")
```

Comment: Why not just take the absolute value of the inputs as a first step? Also -- why not just use `small = min(x,y)` rather than that `if ... else` construct? Furthermore -- your indentation doesn't make sense. I doubt that you really have the `while` loop at the bottom inside of the function definition. FInally, `math.gcd()` computes what you are trying to compute much more efficiently.

Comment: just write an if condition for num1 and num2

Comment: Define "this does not function anymore"

Answer (score 0):

You have to make python first check for strings in the input.
Then check for negative numbers, 
If none of these two errors are present it goes ahead to run your code
But if they are let it exit before giving an error
Like so:

```
def computeHCF(x,y):

    if type(x) is str or type(y) is str:
        print("You wrote something that doesn't have any sense!")
        exit()
    elif x < 0 or y < 0 :
        print("You wrote something that doesn't have any sense!")
        exit()
    elif x>y:
        smaller = y
    elif y<x:
        smaller = x
    for i in range(1, smaller+1):
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i
    return hcf

while True:
    num1 = (input("Enter the first number: "))
    num2 = (input("Enter the second number: "))
    print("The H.C.F. of", num1,"and", num2,"is", computeHCF(num1, num2))
    continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

We can simulate what happens in your code when the result is not what we expect.
We noticed that if we insert a negative number, the program stops.
so let's assume num1 = -4 and num2 = 2

```
def computeHCF(x,y): # x = -4, y = 2
    if x>y: # we don't meet this condition
        smaller = y
    else: # we meet this condition
        smaller = x # smaller value is -4
    for i in range(1, smaller+1): # there is nothing in range(1, -3)!!
        # we do not enter here
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i
    return hcf # hcf value has never been retrived, so an error will be raised here
```

you can solve this problem in many ways, two of them are:
set hfc with a base value, so if the conditions in the for loop are not met, the base value will be returned:

```
def computeHCF(x,y):
    hcf = None
```

this code will return:

```
('The H.C.F. of', -4, 'and', 2, 'is', None)
```

or by having the absolute value of x and y:

```
def computeHCF(x,y):
    x = abs(x)
    y = abs(y)
```

this code will return:

```
('The H.C.F. of', -4, 'and', 2, 'is', 2)
```

We also see that if we insert a string or something that can't be interpreted as an int, another error is raised.
This time, the error happens when you read the input:

```
num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
```

in this two lines, you convert anything that the user input to an int, but strings like "Hello World!" can't be converted into an int.
One of the many way to solve this problem, is to use try/except: you try to read the input as an int, but if an error occurs, you do something else.

```
try:
    num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
    num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
    print("The H.C.F. of", num1,"and", num2,"is", computeHCF(num1, num2))
    continue
except:
    print("You write something that doesn't have any sense!")
    continue
```

with this code, the result of the inputs "Hello" and "World!" will be:

```
"You write something that doesn't have any sense!"
```

you catch also the error generated by the function computeHCF(x,y) when x = 0 or y = 0.
At last, you can erase your last two lines, with the "else" statement. That else will be executed only when the condition of the while loop is False, but True is always True!
in the end, your code could be like:

```
def computeHCF(x,y):
    x = abs(x)
    y = abs(y)
    # or hcf = None
    if any([type(x)!=int,type(y)!=int]):
        return hcf
    if x>y:
        smaller = y
    else:
        smaller = x
    for i in range(1, smaller+1):
        if((x % i == 0) and (y % i == 0)):
            hcf = i
    return hcf

while True:
    try:
        num1 = int(input("Enter the first number: "))
        num2 = int(input("Enter the second number: "))
        print("The H.C.F. of", num1,"and", num2,"is", computeHCF(num1, num2))
    except:
        print("You write something that doesn't have any sense!")
    continue
```